# Inside openxml, is the run element the full name?

Tags: ms-word, openxml, openxml-sdk

Recently I was doing something related to openxml and I saw the names of some elements such as **paragraph**, **section** and so on, but the smallest element is called **run**, but the meaning of run stands for running (movement).

```
<w:r>
    <w:t xml:space="preserve"> 1</w:t>
</w:r>
```

I don't know why it is called run, is this run short for some other word? What is this word?

Answer (score 3):

In (at least UK) English the expression "a run of x" means "a series of x".

A run, in this context, is a run of characters.

Nothing to do with sport. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Per the Microsoft documentation:

> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/working-with-runs
>
> The next level of the document hierarchy [after the paragraph] is the
> run, which defines a region of text with a common set of properties. A
> run is represented by an r element, which allows the producer to
> combine breaks, styles, or formatting properties, applying the same
> information to all the parts of the run.

In other words, your Word document consists of "paragraphs", and paragraphs consist of one or more "runs".

One example of creating a separate run would be if you wanted to highlight some text within the paragraph.

Comment: What I cannot find or understand clearly is the use case for these 'runs'.  Also what user actions triggers the creation of them, especially in cases where I see two consecutive runs with no changes in format whatsoever.

Comment: @markcelo: Strong suggestion: if you're not already familiar with OpenXML, then open a Word .docx (it's just a .zip file with a bunch of subdirectories, XML files and other resources), look at "word\document.xml" (you'll have to "pretty print" the XML to make it legible) and look at how text elements ("<w:t>") are wrapped in runs, in paragraphs.  Let's say I wanted to highlight a few words in a paragraph.  The highlighted text would be in a "run".  The unhighlighted text before and after would also be in their own, separate "runs".

Comment: thanks  @paulsm4  . My question/Comment is rather about the design logic behind runs (what use case they fulfill) .

Comment: So your question is answered, correct?  "Highlight some text in a paragraph" would be one use case.  "Bold" or "Italicize" would be other use cases.  See the "working with runs" documentation I cited.  Or look at some "real world" examples by unzipping the components in a .docx and studying the "document.xml" you'll find.

Answer (score 0):

Run can be basically used to append any running text which we intended to see in the document example of run which is use in Footer of the document.

```
   FooterPart footerPart;
   Footer footer1 = new Footer();
   Paragraph paragraph1 = new Paragraph()
   Run run1 = new Run();
   run1.Append(new Text("This is footer text"));
   run1.Append(new Break());
   run1.Append(new Text("CONFIDENTIAL AND PROPRIETARY - All rights reserved."));

   paragraph1.Append(run1);
   footer1.Append(paragraph1);
   footerPart.Footer = footer1;
```